# How can I use Firebase to query an external API and store data in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm teaching myself to use Flutter and I'm making an app that queries The Movie Database API. Currently, I'm having the client query the API on launch but I'm thinking this is not the most efficient way of doing it, and I would rather have the client query a backend service like Firebase to get the same data.

I would appreciate some guidance into where to start in order to setup a periodical process to query the API and use the results as entries into a Firestore DB. I've looked online but I might be using suboptimal keywords since I haven't found a good tutorial or example for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Cloud Functions to build code that runs on Firebase servers to fill your Firebase database, but you can only make HTTP requests to non-Google addresses if you use a paid plan.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html explains how to invoke periodic tasks with Cloud Functions. It utilizes Google AppEngine for that because Cloud Functions doesn't provide that out of the box.